# Difference between .on and addEventListener with react and plot.ly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, plotly

I have a div that contains my chart in Plot.ly.
Looking at the React documentation it was recommended that I use addEventListener in componentDidMount so I attached to my chart a plotly event through addEventListener.

`this.refs.chart.addEventListener('plotly_selected', this._lasso_selection);`

However, when I select some points on my chart nothing displays. Likewise if I try:

`this.refs.chart.on('plotly_selected', this._lasso_selection);`

It doesn't seem to work in my component code.

However when I try running the code in console addEventListener doesn't seem to work while .on does work. I have checked the reference of this.refs.chart and it is correct [i.e. the same as the one I grab in console]

How can I use the plotly_selected event in my component? Moreover why can't I simply add a .on event in componentDidMount and have it work the way it does in console?

Answer (score 0):

Since the Plot.ly API requires a DOM node for the chart, passing it a Ref will not suffice. I am not 100% sure if this is best practice, but an easy fix is to add `.getDOMNode()` to the Ref. Here's a simple example:

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const chart = this.refs.chart.getDOMNode();
    
    var data = [
      {
        x: ['giraffes', 'orangutans', 'monkeys'],
        y: [20, 14, 23],
        type: 'bar'
      }
    ];

    Plotly.newPlot(chart, data);
    chart.on('plotly_hover', this.handleEvent);   
  }
  handleEvent() {
    console.log('Event!')
  }
  render() {
    return(
      <div ref="chart" id="chart" />
    );
  }

}

React.render(<Example/>, document.getElementById('View'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-1.2.0.min.js"></script>

<div id="View"></div>
```

Comment: Hello Fabian, I appear to be getting a "getDOMNode is not a function" error. I've logged out my this.refs.chart and it seems to already be the DOM node.